How to do priori calculations for rust iterators only once
I have a struct, an iterator, and a function that the iterator uses. In the iterator code I have a variable n2 that is calculated each time. This seems unnecessary, n2 only needs to be calculated once, not on each iteration, how do I optimize the code?
fn kronecker_delta_f32<I:Eq>(i: I, j: I) -> f32 {
    if i == j { 1.0 } else { 0.0 } 
}

struct IdentityMatrixIterator {
    i: u128,
    n: u128
}

impl Iterator for IdentityMatrixIterator {
    type Item = f32;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let i = self.i;
        self.i += 1;

        let p = i % (self.n + 1);
        let r = kronecker_delta_f32(p, 0);
        let n2 = self.n * self.n;

        if self.i <= n2 { Some(r) } else { None }
    }
}

I tried putting
let n2 = self.n * self.n;

before the function, but it wouldn't have access to self outside the function, so I am confused.
The code calculates what I expect it to, I just do not know how to optimize so the multiplication only happens once.

You can put n2 into the structure. Actually you don't need n there.

@adymerets OP's code uses self.n to calculate p

First, you should know that today's compilers are very good. Compilers can easily see such simple computation does not change inside the loop and lift it outside of it. In fact, if you will look on godbolt, you will see the assembly is quite long (I showed LLVM IR to ease the view), but the computation of n*n (%n2.i = mul i128 %n, %n) clearly happens outside of the loop (label bb4).
However, the compiler may struggle with more complex computations, especially if there are non-inlined functions involved. In such cases, the easiest fix is just to save the computation as a field of the iterator.

Although as with all performance-related questions, you should benchmark to make sure that saving the computation as a field of the iterator really improves performance. In some situations, it is actually faster to recompute a value than to access it from memory…

@Jmb The compiler can make it access from registers, but of course you're right.
